# TaskList Became empty after adding the last task from the task list

Tags: angularjs

I have a tasklist that contains some task, When I add a task from it, it removes from the list. How Can I avoid that so that I will be available for adding multiple time. 
Here is the view code :-

```
<a ng-if="editable" ng-click="makeManualTasksList();" class="marL10 marB15 showRowInfo freelancerInvoice">Add Custom Tasks </a>
```

And here is the controller code :-

```
$scope.makeManualTasksList = function() {
    $scope.switchToTasksSelection = false;
    $scope.selectBoxMannual = true;
    $scope.availableTasksForSelection = [];
    console.log("$scope.availableTasksForSelection", $scope.availableTasksForSelection);
    var selectFlag = {
        id: -1,
        task: {
            taskName: "Task"
        },
        order: "Task No.",
        service: {
            workOrder: {
                jobNo: "Job No.",
                jobName: "Job Name",
                number: "WO No."
            }
        }
    };
    $scope.availableTasksForSelection.push(selectFlag);
    angular.forEach($scope.capableTaskList, function(task, id) {
        task.quantity = 1;
        if (!task.isSelected) $scope.availableTasksForSelection.push(task);
    });
    $scope.selectedTask = $scope.availableTasksForSelection[0];
    console.log("$scope.selectedTaskpawan", $scope.selectedTask);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable **isSelected** which was causing problem for the list. 
Now. 
In the controller :

```
$scope.availableTasksForSelection.push(selectFlag);
angular.forEach($scope.capableTaskList, function(task, id) {
    task.quantity = 1;
    if (!task.selected) $scope.availableTasksForSelection.push(task);
});
$scope.selectedTask = $scope.availableTasksForSelection[0];
console.log("$scope.selectedTaskpawan", $scope.selectedTask);
```

PS: Thanks to all who had a look at my quetion.